# Groupby consecutive occurrences of two column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with this structure:

```
ID    loc    start    end    a_cn   b_cn
A     1      123      123    1      1
A     1      125      125    1      1
A     1      235      235    1      1
A     1      456      456    2      0
A     1      556      556    2      0
A     1      586      586    2      1
A     1      596      596    2      1
A     1      676      676    1      1
```

What I need to do is to be able to group consecutive rows where `a_cn` and `b_cn` are identical, but not if there is a "gap". In other words, the groups on the above data would be

**Group 1**

```
A     1      123      123    1      1
A     1      125      125    1      1
A     1      235      235    1      1
```

**Group 2**

```
A     1      456      456    2      0
A     1      556      556    2      0
```

**Group 3**

```
A     1      586      586    2      1
A     1      596      596    2      1
```

**Group 4**

```
A     1      676      676    1      1
```

`groupby` alone won't work, because it would group together the first 3 lines and the last one, which is not what I want (I need to do some calculations with `start` and `end` afterwards, so they must stay in order).

This question is similar to [How to groupby with consecutive occurrence of duplicates in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906756/how-to-groupby-with-consecutive-occurrence-of-duplicates-in-pandas) but the solution there only works for a single column and I couldn't figure out how to make it work for 2 columns at the same time.

I've also tested

```
diff = (
    (df["a_cn"] != df["a_cn"].shift()) &
    (df["b_cn"] != df["b_cn"].shift())
).cumsum()
```

but it doesn't really do what I want because it trips on group 3, which has an identical `a_cn` compared to the previous group. As a non working example:

```
>>> diff

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    2
7    2
```

which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare both columns with [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) for `!=` by shifted rows of both columns and then add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if True at least in one column, last added cumulative sum:

```
diff = df[["a_cn","b_cn"]].ne(df[["a_cn","b_cn"]].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
#alternative
diff = (df[["a_cn","b_cn"]] != df[["a_cn","b_cn"]].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
print (diff)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4
dtype: int32
```

Your solution should be changed with `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
diff = (
    (df["a_cn"] != df["a_cn"].shift()) |
    (df["b_cn"] != df["b_cn"].shift())
).cumsum()
print (diff)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Regarding OR instead of AND: whoops, yes, logical error. Even after all these years I still get tangled sometimes. ;)
Regardless, your solution works perfectly. Thanks!