# Pandas groupby over consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given a table,

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |

Instead of a simple `groupby('Id').agg({'Value':'sum'})` which would perform aggregation over all the instances and yield a table with only four rows, I wish the result to aggregate only over the nearby instances and hence maintaining the order the table was created.

The expected output is following,

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 1 | 1 |

If not possible with pandas groupby, any other kind of trick would also be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** If the above example is not helpful, basically what I want is to somehow compress the table with aggregating over 'Value'. The aggregation should be done only over the duplicate 'Id's which occur one exactly after the other.

Comment: Hi, I write *groupby over consecutive duplicates* on a search engine and get an answer to your query right away; did you try that?

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906756/how-to-groupby-with-consecutive-occurrence-of-duplicates-in-pandas helps. As Neither mentioned, google is your best friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answers from eshirvana and wwnde doesn't seem to work for a long dataset. Inspired from answer of wwnde, I found a workaround,

```
# create a series referring to group of identicals
new=[]
i=-1
for item in df.Id:
    if item !=seen:
        i+=1
    seen=items
    new.append(i)

df['temp']=new
```

Now, we groupby over 'temp' column.

```
df.groupby('temp').agg({'Id':max, 'Value':sum}).reset_index(drop=True)
```